# Different HTML pages using the same image, does the browser fetch the image once and use it twice?

Tags: html, browser

I've got an odd question. Say I have two HTML pages index1.html and index2.html. In both the pages is some jpg image called "Hello". When I use the browser to point to say www.testing.com/index1.html the browser will load index1.html and the image Hello.

Now my question is when I go click on some link in index1.html that takes me to index2.html, will the browser look to go to back to the server to get image Hello or will it use the Hello image used in index1.html?

Comment: what you're asking is a question of how the browser manages cache. so "it depends".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the caching headers the server sends out alongside the image.

There are several ways in which caching can be done.

When a resource is served with an expiry date in the future, the browser will use its cached copy until that date is reached (or the cache is emptied or a refresh forced.

Another way is for the server to listen to the  `If-modified-since` request header. The server can then check whether the resource has been modified since that date. If it hasn't, it will return a `304 not modified` status; otherwise, the updated resource.

The [Apache Caching guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html) is a (lengthy) introduction to the subject.

To see in your browser what caching rules apply, open its developer tools and look for the "Net" tab. It's a list of all the requests that were made in connection with the current page. It'll tell you whether a resource was loaded from the server, or a cached copy used.

For example, this result on a Stack Overflow image from Chrome's developer tools:

[image]

suggests the image was cached. When I click that row, I can switch to the "header" view, where I can see the exact caching instructions the server sends:

[image]

It means that as long as the browser has a cached copy of the image, it will keep on using that without ever checking with the server until December 17, 2014.

Comment: It also depends on the URLs: do the URLs used in the references resolve to the same absolute URL? An image may be accessible using different absolute URLs.

Answer (score 0):

Different browsers handle this differently.  It can also depend on user settings.  Users can set the browser to cache nothing if they so desire.